# Search/Clone feature that needs to not be case sensitive and be able to prioritise what is cloned

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, search

I currently have a search feature setup that will breakdown the words you've searched and will then check to see if those words exists in a specific div. If they do it will clone those divs and list them inside another div called `.search-results`. This is currently working well, however I would like to fine tune it with the following:

1. Be able to make it so the search isn't case sensitive. For example if I search 'apples' or 'APPLES' it will still know to clone the div with the word 'Apples' in.
2. The cloned divs that have the most words matching from that of the searched sentence to be placed at the top of the .search-results class, this is just so those elements take precedence over the others that are still containing searched words but perhaps slightly less.

So an example would be if I searched 'Lemon Pineapple Orange' I would only expect two results to appear that are:

```
<div class="box">Lemon Mango Orange</div>
<div class="box">Cherries Pineapple Strawberries Crabapple</div>
```

and it would be in that order because 'Lemon' and 'Orange' are both part of the same div containing two searched words and therefore goes at the top where as the div containing the word Lemon only has one searched word so would go underneath. I hope that makes sense :-)

I hope that all makes sense. Any help would be great. Below is an example of the code which is working well, but like I said I just want to fine tune it. Many thanks.

```js
$("#search-submit").on("click", function() {
  var search = $("#search-input").val();
  if (search !== "") {
    var searchArray = search.split(" ");
    searchArray.forEach(function(searchWord) {
      $(".box").each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":contains(" + searchWord + ")")) {
          $(this).clone(true).appendTo(".search-results");
        }
      });
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <input id="search-input" type="text" />
  <input id="search-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div><br/>
<div class="search-results"></div><br/>
<div class="box">Apples Banana Blueberries</div>
<div class="box">Cherries Pineapple Strawberries</div>
<div class="box">Lemon Mango Orange</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code block you have an example of how you can create (or adapt existing) a jQuery selector. In this case `:containsInsensitiveWithCount` that will act like contains in mode case insensitive and add a `data-matches` attribute with the number of matches.

Then you can sort based on this attribute.

Note that you might have a problem when you search multiple terms, you'll notice that your code creates a clone for each match, so it duplicates a result if it matches different terms. I have not addressed this here.

EDIT: while I was writing, you edited the question exactly about the note I added. Here is a possible solution:

- now the custom selector can accept multiple parameters separated by `,` (it means you can't search a coma now, if problematic, choose another separator)
- the selector loops automatically on the arguments so the count now reflects the total search and avoids duplicates
- fixed the sorting (actually with the help of @RoryMcCrossan, I had forgotten the `.find(".box")`)
- call to the selector simplified, you don't need to do `each` on the `".box"`, just use `$(".box:contains...").clone`

```js
//custom jQuery selector - has to be done only once, at the start of the scripts
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.expr[":"].containsInsensitiveWithCount = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
      var searchArray = arg.split(",");
      var count = 0;
      searchArray.forEach(function(searchWord) {
        //to match the word exactly: this uses a regexp that searches the word detected between either non-word char or start of string and either non-word char or end of the string. If there are matches, result is an array with the matches. 'g' is for global and 'i' for case-insensitive
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\W|^)' + searchWord + '(?=\\W|$)', 'gi');
        var match = $(elem).text().match(reg);
        if(match){
          count += match.length;
        }
        //to match part of the word: works by splitting the text at the searchWord, if it is found, an array of length (number of occurences + 1) is returned, or else an array with original string (length 1)
        //count += $(elem).text().toUpperCase().split(searchWord.toUpperCase()).length - 1;
      });
      $(elem).attr("data-matches", count);
      return count > 0;
    };
  });
});

$("#search-submit").on("click", function() {
  var search = $("#search-input").val(), result = $(".search-results");
  result.empty();
  if (search !== "") {
    $(".box:containsInsensitiveWithCount(" + search.replace(/ /g, ",") + ")").clone(true).appendTo(result);
    //the sorting
    result.find(".box").sort(function(a, b) {
      return $(b).data("matches") - $(a).data("matches");
    }).appendTo(result);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <input id="search-input" type="text" />
  <input id="search-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div><br/>
<div class="search-results"></div><br/>
<div class="box">Apples Banana Blueberries</div>
<div class="box">Cherries Pineapple Strawberries</div>
<div class="box">Lemon Mango Orange</div>
```

Comment: @RepublicOfDavid edited the answer with a version that matches the words strictly. I left the part that matches them loosely, but commented, and added explanations. Don't uncomment both parts or you will add both results. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

To make the search case insensitive you can use a regular expression to find the search term within the text of each `.box`.

In addition this regular expression can be used to count the number of matches within the `.box` and then `sort()` by that value once the loop has completed.

Note in the example below that I added 'Crabapple' value to on of the boxes to that it has two instances of 'apple' to search for. This will always force this result to the top.

Finally, note that I added a call to `empty()` the result each time a new search is performed. The previous search results were not being removed in your original example.

```js
let $results = $('.search-results');

$("#search-submit").on("click", function() {
  let searchArray = $("#search-input").val().trim().split(' ');
  $results.empty();
  
  searchArray.forEach(function(word) {
    $(".box").each(function() {    
      let re = new RegExp(word, 'gi');
      let matches = ($(this).text().match(re) || []).length;      
      if (matches != 0) {
        $(this).clone(true).appendTo($results).data('matches', matches);
      }
    });
  });
  
  $results.find('.box').sort((a, b) => $(a).data('matches') < $(b).data('matches') ? 1 : -1).appendTo($results);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <input id="search-input" type="text" value="apple" />
  <input id="search-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div><br/>
<div class="search-results"></div><br/>
<div class="box">Apples Banana Blueberries</div>
<div class="box">Cherries Pineapple Strawberries Crabapple</div>
<div class="box">Lemon Mango Orange</div>
```

*Update*

Given the edit to the question you could amend the above logic to build a single regular expression which evaluates all words entered at once:

```js
let $results = $('.search-results');

$("#search-submit").on("click", function() {
  $results.empty();
  let exp = $("#search-input").val().trim().replace(/\s+/g, '|');
  let re = new RegExp(exp, 'gi');

  $(".box").each(function() {
    let matches = ($(this).text().match(re) || []).length;
    if (matches != 0) {
      $(this).clone(true).appendTo($results).data('matches', matches);
    }
  });

  $results.find('.box').sort((a, b) => $(a).data('matches') < $(b).data('matches') ? 1 : -1).appendTo($results);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <input id="search-input" type="text" value="Lemon Pineapple Orange" />
  <input id="search-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div><br/>
<div class="search-results"></div><br/>
<div class="box">Apples Banana Blueberries</div>
<div class="box">Cherries Pineapple Strawberries</div>
<div class="box">Lemon Mango Orange</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks Rory, this is good, search case insensitive works perfectly however regarding the order, I see what exactly what you have done but I think I explained it wrong in the first place, I have updated the post with an example of what I mean for this, thank you Rory.

Comment: No problem, I updated the answer with a slightly tweaked approach